# How Laravel maintains persistent database connection

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, amazon-rds

I was developing a Laravel application in LAMP setup at my local machine( my laptop).

For testing purpose, I tried to use the mysql service of `Aws RDS` instead my local `mysql server`. Found that, an API call which have only one db call with no join (query: *show tables*) - takes on average 12s. This is ridiculous. When I am using local mysql server, it is around than 600ms. Until now, PDO::ATTR_PERSISTANT was not enabled.

Logging in `Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php` [ inside `createConnection()` method ], I found that, this method is called for each request. This is for both mysql server.

Then, I set `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTANT` to `true`. But response time's are similar.

After looking a more closer, found this in the same file:

```
/**
 * Create a new PDO connection instance.
 *
 * @param  string  $dsn
 * @param  string  $username
 * @param  string  $password
 * @param  array  $options
 * @return \PDO
 */
protected function createPdoConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options)
{
    if (class_exists(PDOConnection::class) && ! $this->isPersistentConnection($options)) {
        return new PDOConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }

    return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
}
```

And `PDOConnection` - *which `extends PDO`, that is used when persistent is false* - constructor is:

```
public function __construct($dsn, $user = null, $password = null, array $options = null)
{
    try {
        parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, ['Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement', []]);
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
        throw new PDOException($exception);
    }
}
```

It seems, setting `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTANT` to `true` has no effect.
This made me confused.

1. How actually persistent database connection plays in Laravel?
2. What was the reason behind long response time (with mysql service of `Aws RDS`) ?

Answer (score 8):

MySQL is a database that is known for having a lightweight connection overhead.  For this reason, concerns in regards to connection reuse rarely surface, but in any case, connections in PHP are tied to processes.  You really will only see the benefit of connection reuse under load, where there are enough php processes running that a sustained PHP process gets around to re-using a mysql client connection.

In other words, your mysql client connections can/will/might be closed depending on your web server configuration, even if you are using persistent mysql connections, or a new connection will need to happen if the apache process for a request does not already have a persistent connection available.

Even if you have a persistent connection available, this does NOT mean that things will be faster in your scenario, because the assumption you are making is that *connection time to the RDS across the public internet is slow*, when in reality, **the entire mysql client connection from your localhost application across the public internet is slow**.  Queries will be slow, result set fetching will be slow, and overall it is going to be a poor experience.

A connection taking 12 seconds isn't something you would see if you were hosting your entire site on AWS and using RDS for your data store. It will be much closer to the type of performance you get on your localhost with a local database.

Furthermore, the entire predicate of the idea isn't good.

1. RDS is a premium priced product.  You shouldn't be using that for Development at all.  If you are using free tier, the database performance for anything but a tiny db is going to be pretty slow.
2. MySQL intrinsically has no network layer security.  Your AWS deployment should be using VPC where the RDS is in the VPC, your PHP application servers are in the VPC.
3. There is nothing special in your app to using RDS.  It looks to your application like any other mysql database with a non-localhost -h parameter.

You are trying to tune something that literally nobody would use in the real world, thus you are trying to solve a problem of your own making that is of no long term benefit to your project.

With that said, if you want to understand better why you are experiencing what you are, and how both PHP and associated resource handles work, a database that DOES have a heavyweight and time consuming connection process is Oracle.  People using Oracle with PHP legitimately have to be concerned with connection reuse, because Oracle expects that a connection will be made, and then many "sessions" will occur.  Although this [Oracle Cookbook article](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/coggeshall-persist-084844.html) is somewhat old now, it does a good job illustrating the association between PHP processes (at least with Apache and Mod_php) and database connections.

Last but not least, this topic is complicated by the fact that there are a number of different ways you can run PHP.  Apache has several different configurations, which is different from IIS, which is different from Nginx/php-fpm which has become popular in recent years.  [This SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432948/fully-understanding-pdo-attr-persistent) already addressed the specific PDO param you are trying to use, which ultimately just passes it through to the MySQL client library, along with some important caveats and concerns that explain why MySQL connections are rarely worth the potential for trouble they might cause.

Comment: FYI, I have aws-rds paid service for production purpose. As I mentioned was trying to experiment. Another point is, I was not trying to solve anything but to digging down, how thing work under the hood actually. Most of the time, attacking language doesn't help. By the way, thanks for reading a long question and writing an answer.

Comment: @MASh: apologies if you took anything I wrote as attacking.  At times, I'm just trying to be efficient and blunt.  We could have spent time with 10 questions teasing out where you are coming from, but I am trying to limit that down in my SO activity.

Comment: FWIW, I have been using AWS with most of my clients for something like 6+ years now, and RDS, whether the client pays for it or not, is very expensive, so I don't use it unless it's production.  For example, I now stop dev RDS for a client on a daily basis and only start it up if I'm actually using it.  Hopefully my points in regards to its use, will help you figure out best practices ie. using it within a VPC.

Comment: I also do not use RDS for dev. This time I tried as it was a decision of our dev team ( I wish I could speak that cause publicly )

Comment: It's ok to use it for Dev, perhaps to have a dev/test platform where your app server is in AWS too.  The problem you found is when you try local dev to RDS ;)  The argument NOT to do it is in my answer -- MySQL across the public internet is literally disclosing your data unless you are wrapping it all in SSL.  That would be your argument to them for why this is a bad idea for dev.  ;)

Comment: As per you are using RDS for 6 years+, want to ask another question, if my app server(ec2) is in singapore region and RDS at N. California, how much will increase response time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184776/discussion-between-gview-and-mash).